# How to remove all occurrence with a specific pattern?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
EN;05;UK;55;EN;66;US;87;US;89;EN;66;UK;87;
```

I want remove all the `EN` occurrence, so the final string should be:

```
UK;55;US;87;US;89;UK;87;
```

I can remove the `EN` using `string.Replace("EN", "")` but how to remove also the number?

Comment: You can either replace with a loop or regular expression. I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will propose an alternative not using RegEx. This will work if the number following the abbreviation is more than two characters.

```
    public static string RemoveDataPoints(this string data, string indentifier)
    {
        var temp = "";
        var fields = data.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int i=0; i<fields.Length; i=i+2)
        {
            if (!fields[i].Equals(indentifier))
            {
                temp += String.Format("{0};{1};", fields[i], fields[i + 1]);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Then call:

```
var output = "EN;05;UK;55;EN;66;US;87;US;89;EN;66;UK;87;".RemoveDataPoints("EN");
```

Comment: welcome - improvements can be made to this depening on your application requirment (error handling, maybe making temp a StringBuilder) I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a regular expression:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "EN\\;\\d{2}\\;", "");
```

where `input` is your string, EN;05;UK;55;EN;66;US;87;US;89;EN;66;UK;87;.

Comment: I don't mind regualr expressions, but what if the data changes at all, you should look ahead to the next semi-colon not just get two characters